# how to whitelist host header in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, amazon-eks

Deployed the nifi in eks cluster when tried to access the nifi from loadbalancer gives following error:

System Error

The request contained an invalid host header [abc.com] in the request [/nifi].

Check for request manipulation or third-party intercept.

Valid host headers are [empty] or:

127.0.0.1 
127.0.0.1:8443
localhost
localhost:8443
::1
nifi-deployment-59494c46dc-v4kk6
nifi-deployment-59494c46dc-v4kk6:8443
172.35.3.165
172.35.3.165:8443

How to whitelist loadbalancer dns name in host header check of nifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end of this section from the admin guide explains the host header:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#proxy_configuration